# Lags don't like dummy variables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to define a function lag_and_dummies which will add 2 lags for my data as well as 3-level dummy variables (having in mind how to include them properly in panel data).

Let's consider data :

```
data("EmplUK", package="plm")
head(EmplUK)
  firm year sector   emp    wage capital   output
1    1 1977      7 5.041 13.1516  0.5894  95.7072
2    1 1978      7 5.600 12.3018  0.6318  97.3569
3    1 1979      7 5.015 12.8395  0.6771  99.6083
4    1 1980      7 4.715 13.8039  0.6171 100.5501
5    1 1981      7 4.093 14.2897  0.5076  99.5581
6    1 1982      7 3.166 14.8681  0.4229  98.6151
```

**Function**

```
lag_and_dummies <- function(x) {
  #adding 2 lags to wage
  x <- x %>%
    group_by_at(1) %>%
    mutate(across(wage, dplyr::lag, n = 2, default = NA))
  #deleting NA's
  x <- na.omit(x)
  #creating dummy three-level dummy variables
  x <- within(x, {
    dummy <- as.factor(ave(get(colnames(x)[2]), get(colnames(x)[1]), FUN = function(a) rep_len(1:3, length(a))))
  })
  x <- cbind(x, model.matrix(~ dummy - 1, data = x))
  x
}
```

The strange thing which happens is that three columns for dummy variables are stored in one column. Have a look at View output :

[image]

However if I delete adding lags from lag_and_dummies it works properly i.e.

```
lag_and_dummies <- function(x) {
  x <- within(x, {
    dummy <- as.factor(ave(get(colnames(x)[2]), get(colnames(x)[1]), FUN = function(a) rep_len(1:3, length(a))))
  })
  x <- cbind(x, model.matrix(~ dummy - 1, data = x))
  x
}
```

[image]

Do you know why including lags cause creating dummy variables in one column ?

Answer (score 0):

In your first function your data is grouped. There seems to be some issue when cbind dataframe with a grouped tibble. You can `ungroup` the data and it works as expected.

```
library(dplyr)

lag_and_dummies <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>%
    group_by_at(1) %>%
    mutate(wage = dplyr::lag(wage, n = 2, default = NA))
  x <- na.omit(x)
  #creating dummy three-level dummy variables
  x <- within(x, {
    dummy <- as.factor(ave(get(colnames(x)[2]), 
             get(colnames(x)[1]), FUN = function(a) rep_len(1:3, length(a))))
  })
  x <- cbind(x %>% ungroup, model.matrix(~ dummy - 1, data = x))
  x
}

lag_and_dummies(EmplUK)
```